# isotope whitespace between elements until resize

Tags: jquery-isotope

I have seen many questions about this and no answer (at least not one that helped me).

My setup is very simple - a fluid container (no fixed width) with images in it.

I have set in the CSS that each div item will be 25% and I have set the images in it to fill the div.

I have set the isotope to run only after imagesLoaded.

The problem is that in initial loading, the elements are not positioned correctly. They have some padding between them, and even get out of their container. Only once I resize the window they are properly positioned, even if then I bring the window back to full screen.

Do you know why this happens?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/"></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/440/300/"></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/450/560/"></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/410/270/"></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/440/230/"></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/470/460/"></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/430/780/"></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/520/"></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/420/120/"></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/260/"></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/200/"></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/890/200/"></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main{margin-right:250px;}
#main .item { width: 25%;}
#main .item img { width:100%;height:100%;}
```

JS:

```
var $container = $("#main");
$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: ".item",
    });
});
```

Can anybody explain this behavior...?

**Update**

Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/f35azgdj/2/

Notice how the elements have some space between them, which disappear when resizing.
BTW for some reason here the horizontal spacing is still there even after resizing.

**Another Update**

I think it has something to do with the scrollbars, since when I reduce the number of elements and they fit without a scrollbar, it works.

I think it means that in the initial load isotope is calculating the container size without considering the scrollbar taking a bit from it, so it thinks it has bigger space then it really has, so it position the elements accordingly.
Then, since the elements are set with CSS to 25% of the container, their size is calculated according to the smaller container size (considering the scrollbars) and so it leaves it with  whitespace between them.

Anyone can think of wether its a bug or a wrong setup on my side?

Thanks!

Amos

Comment: Can't reproduce on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f35azgdj/) using Firefox, gives us more info about your browser

Comment: Chrome. I also tested on firefox and it does the same thing. You added this to jsfiddle and it worked good?

Comment: Did you click the link ?

Comment: The fiddle works for me as well (Linux Chrome). Wild guess:Are you waiting until dom ready?

Comment: Gotcha. I clicked the linked, and saw it didn't work. I added the needed libraries. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/f35azgdj/1/

Comment: @Bengt - My code runs in the end and in any case it is attached to the imagesloaded event... Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f35azgdj/1/

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to make the bug look better (just made the left margin smaller): http://jsfiddle.net/f35azgdj/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, so I found the issue and as far as I can see it's bug.

It happens when you have more elements then the size of the screen, so a vertical scroll bar appears.

This scroll bar is taking some space of the screen, so the container div is now smaller.

The problem is that isotope is calculating the size of the container BEFORE the scroll bar appears, so it thinks there is a little more space, and it positioning the elements accordingly.

Then the elements themselves are calculated according to the correct size of the container, meaning they are a bit smaller, and this cause whitespace to appear between them. Another effect is that they are overflowing from the size of the container, and thus also horizontal bar appears.

When resizing, the container size is recalculated, and this time the vertical bar is taking into consideration, so it all get fixed.

So solutions:

**Option one**: Recalculate the container right after the first calculation is done. I have found this to work great:

```
$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: ".item",
        isOriginLeft: false,
    });
    $container.isotope();
});
```

Note the second call to `$container.isotope()`. This will work but will have a double resize effect, and also have a slight moment where you'll have an horizontal scroll bar. But it won't force you to always have a vertical scroll bar as in option 2.

**Option 2**: Add an always-on vertical scroll bar to the page. This will help isotope calculate the container correctly, with considering the scroll bar.

```
html {overflow-y: scroll;}
```

In anyway, I still not sure if this is a bug or something that I need to configure differently. Would love your ideas. Meanwhile this solved my problem so until a better solution comes up I guess I'll mark it as the solution.

Thanks!

Amos

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `html {overflow-y: scroll;}` CSS, add `display: block` to images to remove the extra space beneath images. See http://jsfiddle.net/f35azgdj/6/

Comment: Thanks!! As I believe this scenario (fluid\fullscreen container) is probably popluar, I would strongly suggest writing it somewhere in the docs... I really fought hard for this one until I found the issue\bug...

Comment: @desandro I have the same problem (Istope, packery layout, with imagesloaded script), overlow-y: scroll is set, img { display: block } is also set, but when the images are not cached, I see a lot of padding below the .items.

Comment: html {overflow-y: scroll;}  = lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

I came upon this question via google looking for an answer to a similar problem. My fluid isotope layout was acting wonky: sometimes it went alright, sometimes there was too much white space or images overlapped.

In my case, this was because I had a css transition on the isotope items. I guess isotope measured the items while they were still being animated: on resize they started to transition into other values (due to my widths being in percentage of the viewport and transition property being set) thus isotope started to do its maths with the wrong values.

Since I needed only the transforms to be animated I changed

```
.grid-item {
  transition: 400ms all;
}
```

into

```
.grid-item {
  transition: 400ms transform;
}
```

and it was all right.

Maybe this will save somebody some time.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue, and the only way to fix it is to add `html {overflow-y: scroll;}`but it breaks some modal layout. So I used an extra class to `html` with `overflow-y: scroll;` and I remove it right away as soon as Isotope layout is arranged by using:

```
$grid.one( 'arrangeComplete', function() {
  ...
});
```

I hope it helps. BTW I cannot understand why this issue is not commonly known and fixed...